# Jenkins - set variable from file not working in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I'm unable to assign variable from file output. It doesn't pring the variable.  Any suggestions? This is inside jenkins.

```
bat ''' "C:\\Program Files\\Fortify\\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_20.2.0\\bin\\FPRUtility.bat" -categoryIssueCounts -listIssues -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:low" -project C:\\var\\jenkins_home\\workspace\\demo-api\\demo-api.fpr | findstr /V "INFO]" | findstr /V "WARN]" > fpr_low.txt '''
```

output:

```
C:\var\jenkins_home\workspace\demo-api>"C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_20.2.0\bin\FPRUtility.bat" -categoryIssueCounts -listIssues -information -search -query "[fortify priority order]:low" -project C:\var\jenkins_home\workspace\demo-api\demo-api.fpr   | findstr /V "INFO]"   | findstr /V "WARN]"  1>fpr_low.txt 
[Pipeline] bat
```

Output of `type fpr_low.txt` shows that it was successfully written. But when trying to `set and print` it doesn't work.

```
bat ''' set /p FPR_LOW=<fpr_low.txt '''
bat ''' echo %FPR_LOW% ''''
```

output:

```
C:\var\jenkins_home\workspace\demo-api>set /p FPR_LOW= 0<fpr_low.txt 
[Pipeline] bat

C:\var\jenkins_home\workspace\demo-api>echo %FPR_LOW% 
%FPR_LOW%
```

Comment: okay but why doesn't file output doesn't work? I'm redirecting the output to a file and reading into it a variable but unable to print it.

Comment: Btw does your first comment missing `I`? shouldn't it be `do set "FPR_LOW=%%I"`